# Filter products on basis of user stripe customer portal

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

[I did the Stripe integration,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ7bh.png) I am using the Stripe Checkout and Stripe customer portal for payments management. I have 2 types of users, Students and Teachers. I want to show them subscription on the Customer portal based to their role. The Stripe is giving us the option for the product that we want to show but I am unable to figure out how to show the products to both the users based on their roles so that the Teacher don't see the Students products and the Students do not see the Teachers products.

Answer (score 1):

If you need multiple Customer Portal configurations, you can do so via the API[1]. You can specify what products and prices are allowed in each configuration by passing them in to the `features.subscription_update.products` parameter[2] of the `billingPortal.configurations.create` call.

Then when creating the Customer Portal session, you can pass in the ID for your Student or Teacher configuration to the `configuration` parameter[3] of the `sessions.create` function.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal#configure

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-products

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create#create_portal_session-configuration

Comment: You suggest creating a new portal configuration each time you need to open the portal? Isn't their a way to create 2 configurations that will be reused?

Comment: You should only create each configuration once and re-use it. I did not mean to imply that a new configuration should be created for each session, will edit my answer for clarity.